# Nested View with nested buttons -- Why don't the buttons move with the parent view?

Tags: iphone, ios, interface-builder

In interface builder I created a view, interfaced with the code and in that view I nested two buttons. On loading of the view I hide the view.

How come when I animate the view down, the buttons don't come with it? Why do I also have to reset their frames? Aren't frames relative to the parent view?

Answer (score 0):

They are relative.  I would make sure that your buttons are on the correct view and that they are connected properly.

Also check how the view is wired in and that it is connected to the proper controller.

Comment: ???  That is how I would do it.  Anytime I have an issue in IB, I step into each element and see how it is wired.  This happens especially when I rebuild old code with new Xcode SDKs.